# Create Listbox.ItemTemplate for each item XAML C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a problem. I have listbox.ItemTemplate with Grid inside.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Foreground="Black" FontSize="23" Height="470">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,40" Height="80">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="stopName_TextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="23"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="time_TextBlock" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Time}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="23"/>
                                        <Grid x:Name="firstGraphic" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Height="40" Fill="#2575B0" Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                            <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Fill="#2575B0"  Height="20" Width="20"/>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <Grid x:Name="midleGraphic" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Rectangle Height="80" Width="10" Fill="#2575B0"/>
                                            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="30"  Fill="#2575B0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <Grid x:Name="lastGraphic" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Height="40" Fill="#2575B0" Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            <Ellipse Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Width="20" Fill="#2575B0"/>
                                        </Grid>


                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

My listbox will have 20-25 items. First item will have firstGrahic Grid. Last item - lastGraphic Grid. And the others - midleGraphic Grid. I created all this Grids, but a dont know how I can find this Grids in C# code. I want change Visability property for them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(mainList[i]);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Grid grid = (Grid)this.listBox.FindName("firstGraphic");
                    grid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
```

This example with first Item, but object grid = null.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see your model contains properties Title and Time which are bound to TextBlocks. You can also add new propery to the model, for example:

```
public Visibility FirstGraphicVisibility { get; set; }
```

and bind it to the Grid `Visibility`, eg:

```
<Grid x:Name="firstGraphic" Visibility="{Binding FirstGraphicVisibility}" Grid.Column="0">
```

next just change FirstGraphicVisibility propery in your source list `mainList` and set `ItemsSource` of `ListBox`:

```
ListBox.ItemsSource = mainList;
```